# difference between rvm gemset list and rvm list gemsets

Tags: ruby, rvm

**rvm list gemsets**  shows the install rvm gemsets list and

**rvm gemset list**  shows the list of gemsets for specific selected rvm gemsets.

Is it the right explanation?

Please help me to clear this means correct explanation, when to use and how it is helpful?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6):

**rvm list gemsets** shows the all created rvm gemsets list for all ruby versions.

```
for example
   ruby-1.9.3@a [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3@b [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3@c [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0@a [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0@b [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.0.0@c [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.1.0@a [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.1.0@b [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.1.0@c [ i686 ]
=> ruby-2.1.2@d [ i686 ]
```

**rvm gemset list** shows the list of gemsets for current ruby versions.

for example

```
gemsets for ruby-2.1.2 (found in /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2)
   (default)
   a
   b
   c
=> d
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **rvm list**

   - Basically will list out the ruby versions installed and its exact version with the patch release, this will also point the current rvm, whether its currently being used or used and its default and default rvm rubies.

     ```
     =* ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
     *ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
     # => - current
     # =* - current && default
     #  * - default
     ```
2. **rvm list gemsets**

   - It would list the rvms along with its gemset created for the respective rvm
     eg:

     - `ruby-2.0.0-p451` has got rails3, rails3.2
     - `ruby-2.1.0@rails4` [ x86_64 ] has rails4 as lone gemset.

       ```
       rvm gemsets
       => ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.0.0-p451@global [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3.2 [ x86_64 ] 
       ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.1.1@global [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.1.0@rails4 [ x86_64 ]
       ```
3. **rvm gemset list**

   - It would list the current rvm's gemsets
     eg:
       1. using rvm ruby-2.0.0-p451

     ```
         $ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p451
         $ rvm gemset list
           gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p451 (found in /Users/macbook-chanakya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451)

         =>(default)
            global
            rails3
            rails3.2
     ```

     2. using rvm ruby-2.1.1

     ```
      $ rvm use ruby-2.1.1
       /Users/macbook-chanakya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
       $ rvm gemset list
       gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /Users/macbook-chanakya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
       =>(default)
          global
          rails4
     ```